# What does 'Running this application turns off the Desktop Window Manager' signify?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, manifest, directdraw

MS states, with regard to the [Application Manifest compatibility section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ### Manifestation of Change
>
> Applications without a Compatibility section in their manifest will
>   receive Windows Vista behavior by default on Windows 7 and future
>   Windows versions. (...)
>
> (...)
>
> #### DirectDraw Lock
>
> - Windows 7: Applications manifested for Windows 7 cannot (...)
> - Windows Vista (default): Applications will be able to (...) **Running the application turns off [Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager).**

The note is repeated for the next DirectDraw entry.

What the heck does this signify? None of or desktop (MFC) apps defines a compatibility manifest, but we've never noticed anything on "turning off" on any Desktop.

Comment: AFAIK it basically means Windows 7 switches the theme from Aero to Basic. So maybe either you aren't using Aero anyway or your program doesn't use DirectDraw as described.

Comment: @cremno - Ah. Doh. It only does this when the DirectDraw stuff is actually used. Now that's something :-) Guess it makes sense too. We're using Aero, but I don't think we're using DDraw.